# SSIS NULL(DT_WSTR,10) doesn't return NULL

Tags: sql-server, ssis, null

I want to set empty string to NULL value for column "OLD_LEASE_NUMBER" in my SSIS package so here is the formula

```
TRIM(OLD_LEASE_NUMBER) == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,10) : TRIM(OLD_LEASE_NUMBER)
```

When I do select on my SQL table, it doesn't show NULL for this column. This derived column is done right before inserting records to the table. The field is OLD_LEASE_NUMBER(nvarchar(10),null)

Why doesn't the formula work? How can I set NULL value if this is not the right method?

**Update:** The destination is OLE DB and it is the table on SQL server. It has no default value. Using LEN return the same result. Access mode is "OpenRowset Using FastLoad" and FastLoadKeepNull is true.

Sorry the image doesn't display.

**NEW UPDATE:**
Sorry my bad, I didn't look at all records in the table. It is actually NOT null for only first 30 rows. Why???

Comment: What destination component are you using and how do you have it configured?

Comment: Is the destination table a SQL Server table? Are you using "fast load", and if so, do you have "keep nulls" checked? Does the table have a default on that column? What does `LEN(OLD_LEASE_NUMBER)` show for the inserted rows?

Comment: Yes, the destination is the table on SQL server. It has no default value. Using LEN return the same result. Access mode is "OpenRowset Using FastLoad" and FastLoadKeepNull is true.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM([ColumnName])))==0 ? NULL(DT_WSTR, 10) : LTRIM(RTRIM([ColumnName]))
```

Comment: I tried that too after posting this. I got the same result.

Comment: right click in your table and select `design` then in third column you will see `Allow nulls` and `checked the case ` finally `save your modification`

Comment: It is checked. In fact, all the fields are allow nulls

Comment: Yes. I tried that. Same result. I have a feeling this must be a very silly mistake

Comment: what's the `data type` of the your column `OLD_LEASE_NUMBER`

Comment: OLD_LEASE_NUMBER(nvarchar(10),null)

Comment: I found my mistake. Sorry. I had another data flow that add 30 records to the same table as for testing and suppose to be disable but it wasn't. Thank you @download download for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. Thanks for trying to help me.

I had another data flow that add 30 records to the same table as for testing and suppose to be disable but it wasn't. Duh